# Apache tomcat reloads context multiple times

Tags: tomcat, server, web-applications, tomcat8

I have 2 webapps running in my tomcat. Normally when I start tomcat, I can see both works fine. I need to run one webapp on another port, say 8888 and for the same purpose I have added below Service block in server.xml

```
<Service name="api_service">
    <Connector port="8888" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" />
    <Engine name="api_engine" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false">
                    <Context docBase="api.war" path="/api2" reloadable="false"/>
            </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

after adding this I can access service on 8888 port but in logs I can see that api webapp service context is loaded multiple times (3 in my case). How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved:
If we add context/engine for existing web apps then it will get loaded twice.

This can be handled by separating webapps into another directory.

Comment: There is a warning in [Tomcat's documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment) about this kind of configuration: _"When using automatic deployment, the `docBase` defined by an XML Context file should be outside of the `appBase` directory. If this is not the case, difficulties may be experienced deploying the web application or the application may be deployed twice."_